# MD5 entire drive: skip files if size, timestamp, path match (already hashed)

Tags: windows, list, powershell, hash, metadata

The script below exports file metadata into a .csv file.

I am trying to modify it, so if I run the script again it **updates** the existing .csv with whatever changes occured in the drive since the script was run the last time (i.e., the .csv is updated so it exactly mirrors the drive's current state). *I am writing "updated" as not to hash those files that already been hashed (to save time).*

1. it should **NOT re-calculate those files' MD5 whose
   LWT,size,path,filename.ext has not changed**.
2. if a file's LWT,size,path,filename.ext listed in . csv is not present in the
   drive any more, then **delete** from .csv
3. calculate the **full MD5,LWT,size,path,filename.ext** for all files that are not in the .csv (i.e., **all new, renamed, and edited files**)

Powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File |
  Select-Object -Property @{n="Hash"
                            e={get-filehash -algorithm MD5 -path $_.FullName | Select-object -expandproperty Hash}
                           }, LastWriteTime, Length, FullName |
  Export-Csv filelistcsv_MD5_LWT_size_path_file.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Any hints what I am missing?

Comment: You're kind of going beyond the scope of what you've written by a fair amount.  You'd have to write logic that takes the current object and compares it to whatever line matches in the CSV.  So ideally, you'd `Import-Csv` and run comparisons to the object you're working on.  When you find a change, I suppose you could utilize Get/Set-Content to remove the line that offends.  Btw, you can remove the `|Select -expand` and just wrap the command in parens and use `.Hash`

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that's the part you touching that I am having the problem with. If you are aware a template or other guidance for the comparison, please point me toward.

Comment: Everyone that works on data stored in `csv`s works on it a little differently, so there's not really a template.  You can cut off the `Export-Csv` from your pipeline and store that in a variable, then `Import-Csv` on your existing file to run comparisons on like-objects.  Then the logic is up to you to figure out.